# Can we get pysparks distrubited processing advantage while training multiple dataframes using merlion package?

Tags: pyspark, salesforce-merlion

We are trying to train and save several   univariate timeseries dataframe parallely using Salesforce's merlion package. The problem we are facing, since there are several dataframes involved..we are not able to utilize spark's parallel processing during split of data or during training or test.
Is there any way where we can send the consolidated dataframe to merkion and it trains and saves model based on a identifier column ? Any other way please ?

Not able to figure out how exactly to design my pyspark code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.